# mongodb : Increasing max connections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

i need your help in solving this

this is the result of my `ulimit -a` on my linux server

```
   core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 10000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 24576
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Right now this is the result of my MongoDB

```
db.serverStatus().connections

{ "current" : 4, "available" : 5996 }
```

I want to increase the MongoDb connections more to 10000 .

I have tried different options like in my mongod1.conf

```
fork    = true
port    = 27017
maxConns = 10000
```

and also this while starting mongodb

```
mongod ulimit -n 10000  --config mongod1.conf
```

but nothing worked and all failed , please let me know how can i increase the connections to 10000 in my case , thanks in advance .

Comment: What is the maximum allowed file descriptor value in your `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`? You need to bump that up too.

Comment: i have updated the enteries as per the request

Comment: You need to have the maximum file descriptions more than 10000 since your background processes use some of them. `ulimit -n 25000` should do it.

Comment: thanks Kashyap , but how can i change that to 25000 ??

Answer (score 8):

You also need bump up the number of file descriptors and number of file descriptors per process that the Linux kernel allows.

In Linux, this should be configured by editing the file at `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` or by the `sysctl` utility.

- Edit the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file and add `fs.file-max = 50000`. This sets the maximum file descriptors that can run as a system-wide limit.
- Running `ulimit -n 50000` sets the user-wide limit for the maximum number of file descriptors open.

Check this link for a more descriptive write-up for editing the limits on a linux machine: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/

Answer (score 6):

**Method 1** If you use **systemd** (*systemctl restart mongod*)

```
sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/mongod.service.d/
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/mongod.service.d/limits.conf
```

then add:

```
[Service]
LimitFSIZE=infinity
LimitCPU=infinity
LimitAS=infinity
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
LimitNOFILE=64000
LimitNPROC=64000
```

Then execute:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart mongod
```

**Method 2**  If NO **systemd** (*service mongod restart*)

```
sudo vi /etc/security/limits.d/99-mongodb.conf
```

Add something like:

```
*       -       nproc   64000
*       -       nofile  64000
*       -       fsize   unlimited
*       -       cpu     unlimited
*       -       memlock unlimited
*       -       as      unlimited
*       -       rss     unlimited
```

Note that * it's a wildcard. But you could use a specific user or group.
Then restart session and mongod.

Comment: Thanks it did work for me like a charm. Waster couple of hours to understand the root issue.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
--maxConns arg       max number of simultaneous connections
```

(Source: **[mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--ipv6)** documentation)

Answer (score 3):

It seems MongoDB has no limit on incoming connections and you should modify system-wide limit, see official doc:

> Unless constrained by system-wide limits, MongoDB has no limit on incoming connections. On Unix-based systems, you can modify system limits using the `ulimit` command, or by editing your system’s `/etc/sysctl` file. See [UNIX ulimit Settings](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/) for more information.

Recommended ulimit Settings(offical doc):

> -f (file size): unlimited
>
> -t (cpu time): unlimited
>
> -v (virtual memory): unlimited
>
> -n (open files): 64000
>
> -m (memory size): unlimited
>
> -u (processes/threads): 64000

Remember to **restart** your `mongod` and `mongos` instances after changing the ulimit settings to ensure that the changes take effect.

Source:
[number-of-connections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/analyzing-mongodb-performance/#number-of-connections)
[recommended-ulimit-settings](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-ulimit-settings)

Comment: I don't think Mongod can accept unlimited number of connections. The [global default is 65536](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/configuration-options/#net.maxIncomingConnections)

Answer (score 1):

You might need to change the hard limits in `/etc/limits.conf` or `/etc/security/limits.conf` depending on your distribution.