# How many connections could node's mongoose and mongodb themselves handle? Will the server crash?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, server

I was thinking about building some kind of API built on NodeJS with mongoose. I read that mongoose uses 1 connection per app.

But let us say that we have 300,000 users joining a room to answer some questions (real-time), will mongoose/mongodb handle it? Or will the server itself even handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Thinking on the database side only:

The mongod executable have a parameter ([--maxConns](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-maxconns)) for setting the maximum number of connections, prior to v2.6 you had a limit for that. Now, as the docs say: "This setting has no effect if it is higher than your operating system’s configured maximum connection tracking threshold", see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713415/mongodb-increasing-max-connections-in-mongodb) for linux.

Besides that you MUST consider a [sharded cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/) for this kind of load.