# Why does my node.js app get "hung up" when I send more then 50000 queries simultaneously?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, express

**Moving to other question**

Here is [final question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46492885/why-while-mongo-is-thinking-i-cant-access-my-express-served-pages) on this topic. I removed Express from the equationand generally cleared the question.

---

Before you say something like "fool, do them in series" or something like this, I want to mention, that this code will never be used on production.  I googled for few days and ran tests, and so on and now I need some help.

If you wish to see some **higher level question** - here [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46492885/why-while-mongo-is-thinking-i-cant-access-my-express-served-pages) is.

**Test rig:**

- Windows 10
- Mongo 3.2.11
- Node 6.11.3
- Express 4.15.4

**Problem:**

I have 100000 elements, which I want to check against some collection with find/findOne/whatever.

While I am doing this:

Mongo is fine - checking with logs, mongostat and simply connecting to it and querying somethings.

Node is partially fine - checking with some delayed console.log works fine, **but** if I try to open my app using browser (that is why I included express framework in tags section) it's loading until I ran into server timeout.

There is most simple setting for the page, without any connection to database or anything like it:

```
router.get('/',function(req, res) {
    res.send({result:"OK"});
});
```

And it hangs. I even manually catch [server timeout](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback) to check this.

### The question is why? Everything is asynchronous, all the "resources" are fine and working. What is the problem?

P.S. Mongostats show interesting things - first it shows adding 2000-3000 queries per line, then 0, 0, 0 ... again few thousands and then 0 again and again. 
Here is a [paste](https://pastebin.com/sBeXKZRz)

---

Here is my code, if you will want to test exactly like I do

```
    var t = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Timeout fired in 30 seconds");
    }, 30 * 1000);


    var testArtists = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        testArtists[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    }

    async.map(testArtists, function (artist, callback) {

        db.get().collection('someCollection').
            findOne(
            { "unimportant": testArtists[0] },
            function (err, discogsArtist) {
                if (err) return callback(err);
                return callback(null, "OK");
            }
            );
    }, function (err, results) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        return console.log("somehow finished");
    });
```

---

And here are some errors I got once, maybe they can help, somehow:

```
{ MongoError: connection 4 to localhost:27017 timed out
    at Function.MongoError.create (E:\blablabla\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:29:11)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\blablabla\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:198:20)
    at Socket.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:338:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'connection 4 to localhost:27017 timed out' }
Something went wrong when retrieving an access token read ECONNRESET
{ Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:568:26) code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
{ Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:568:26) code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
```

Thanks in advance!

---

**UPDATE 1**

Updated my code to insert objects - now we can see that some random number of objects are inserted (60000-80000) and then everything goes silent.

---

**UPDATE 2**

### Looked at Express logs in realtime. There is no  call at all, so express seems to be out of question. For now.

**UPDATE 3**

After making the [pool](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/reference/pool/) to 1000 connections everything now works super quickly and finish in time. But this is just scaling solution, like "buy more RAM". I want to know why asynchronous use of database prevents serving pages from browser. 
There is distinct connection between MongoClient pool size and Node serving pages. When mongo driver takes all his allocated pool in, Node stop serving the pages. Why? And how to fight it?

Comment: Start with increasing file descriptor limits. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713415/mongodb-increasing-max-connections-in-mongodb

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to find how to do this on Windows

Comment: It seems that Windows has no limit for this. Or, from other info process can have 16.711.680 handles opened simultaneously.

Comment: Have a look at memory consumption. You may be hitting Paging file. Depends on how much memory you have.

Comment: I have 8GB. While executing inserts I have ~500 MB for node and 40 MB for mongod