# Why while Mongo is "thinking", I can't access my express served pages?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

**Moving to other question**

Here is [final question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515872/why-http-server-failes-to-deliver-a-page-if-with-native-mongo-driver-for-nodejs) on this topic. I removed Express from the equationand generally cleared the question.

---

I have a linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46490800/why-do-my-node-js-app-hangs-up-when-i-send-more-then-50000-queries-simultaneou?noredirect=1#comment79938956_46490800) which is much more detailed, and yet I want to have a question as simple as possible. For this I will omit most the details at all.

Visualize most basic node+express+mongo application.
If I give mongo some large async task (large array of tasks), then express (or node? Do not know), stops supplying my users with pages. With debugger help I know that it even does not go inside respected router. 
Why?

**UPDATE 1**
From Express logs - seems that when I try to reach http://localhost Node does not push it to express.

**UPDATE 2**
After few more hours of testing now I can see that there is distinct connection between MongoClient (node driver for mongo) [pool size](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/reference/pool/) and Node serving pages. When mongo driver takes all his allocated pool in, Node stop serving the pages. 
Why? And how to fight it?

Comment: Does the second request get processed after Mongo finishes thinking?  I've had that happen and it turned out my request wasn't actually asynchronous.  I fixed it by running the Mongo requests in a timeout.  That was a while ago - there might be better ways to do it now.  If that's the problem you're having.

Comment: Second request to server is procedure with no problems. I'm using async.map to fire my mongo requests (which are handled by nodejs mongo driver) - should  that be enough?

Comment: IIRC, the issue was that my request to mongo was not async - it was blocking while the http request was active; so I had to move that to a background task.

Comment: Nope. Everything async. here :) I double checked to be safe. Please see question update.

Comment: Oh!  That sounds like a different problem that I've been up against - I can execute ~1500 requests and the DB stops working.  I've figured out it's because I'm not closing my connections, but I haven't found a method that I like for doing that.  (Even in the documentation examples, `.close()` is called "far away" from where the connection is created.)  So I don't *know* that's the issue.

Comment: What your mongostats say? Even without any tweaks I can execute ~50000 simple requests without any errors from DB. And even if I do more (100k+) and got errors and everything hangs, after awhile (I think it comes from [link](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/reference/connecting/connection-settings/)timeout) I can query  the DB from shell

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea ... this was almost a year ago, and I got sidetracked