# Why http.server failes to deliver a page if with native mongo driver for NodeJS running more tasks in parallel that his pool size

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

**Stack:**

- Mongo native driver 2.2
- NodeJS v 6.11.3
- Windows 10

If I launch more task for driver than his pool size in parallel, I can not get any response from my NodeJS http server.

**Example:**

I use async's lib *async.each* to call 50 000 inserts using mongo driver with [pool size](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/reference/connecting/connection-settings/) set to 1
While this tasks are running (slowly, cause we can have only one query running at the moment), I can not fetch any page from my server. I can't even see this request anywhere. 
The question is why?

**FAQ**

1. I can increase pool size for driver or use async.eachSeries, if I
   want just to solve current situation.
2. I have new Node so [max sockets](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets) for agents are set to *Infinity*
   by default, so [this brilliant article](https://www.future-processing.pl/blog/on-problems-with-threads-in-node-js/) seems to be too old.
3. My RAM and CPU are feeling fine all times. Disk I/O is OK too.
4. I will gladly use read articles on this topic, but I really need
   someone to chew this for me

Here is some code to "try this at home"

```
const mongoUrl = "mongodb://******";
var db = require('./db'); //basic database workflows

const http = require("http");
const async = require('async');

db.connect(mongoUrl, (err, database) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    } else {
        server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
            response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
            response.write("Hello World");
            response.end();
        }).listen(8888);

        console.log("running on 8888");



        var t = setTimeout(function () {
            //here we can see that after 30s node is still working alright
            console.log("Timeout fired in 30 seconds - I'm ok, I can fire timeouts!");
        }, 30 * 1000);


        //let's create a giant array for async.each
        var testArray = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 60000; i++) {
            testArray[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
        }

        //clear the collection
        db.get().collection('someCollection').drop();

        async.each(testArray, function (artist, callback) {
            //insert to mongo
            db.get().collection('someCollection').
                insert({ "unimportant": artist },
                function (err, result) {
                    if (err) return callback(err);
                    return callback(null, "OK");
                });
        }, function (err, results) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            return console.log("somehow finished");
        });



        console.log("No blocking operations before this point - hooray!");

    }
});
```

**db.js**

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var ObjectID = mongodb.ObjectID;

var state = {
  db: null,
};

exports.connect = function(url, done) {
  if (state.db) return done();  

  MongoClient.connect(url, {
      poolSize:1,      //pool size
  }, function(err, db) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    state.db = db;
    state.discogsDB = db.db("discogs");    
    done();
  }); 
};

exports._id = function(id) {
  return new ObjectID(id);
};

exports.get = function() {
  return state.db;
};

exports.getD = function() {
  return state.discogsDB;
};

exports.close = function(done) {
  if (state.db) {
    state.db.close(function(err, result) {
      state.db = null;
      state.mode = null;
      done(err);
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Please include `db.js` as well.

Comment: Included db.js to main question.

Answer (score 0):

When running that code, Node.js takes up an entire CPU core, which almost always means that the event loop is being blocked.

Because `async.each()` runs the iteratee function in parallel, you're basically starting 60K concurrent queries. I think that the MongoDB driver gets overwhelmed by that, also because you're starving it with a very limited pool size.

Even when you would increase the pool size considerably, `async.each()` isn't the correct tool to use. A better solution, in between `async.each()` (parallel) and `async.eachSeries()` (sequentially) would be [`async.eachLimit()`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachLimit), with which you can manage the amount of concurrent "tasks" to run.

Comment: Hi, robertklep! Why 60K concurrent queries overwhelm my driver? I thought Mongo was created to deal with situations like this. If I will have 100K users there will be chance for a situation like this even if I will try to put each of user request to series. My test stand have better CPU and RAM that future server, so that is a bit of an issue

Comment: @Amantel it's not necessarily the amount of queries that you _start_ that is causing the problem, it's the pool size of just 1. It means that you are creating a deliberate bottleneck in your application. Use a decent pool size (at least 10, probably higher) and limit the amount of concurrent queries to about the same (using `async.eachLimit`) and see what sort of results that yields.

Comment: True. I made it 3000, but and that helps, for a time. I saw at [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/) mongo production docs that it should be set to 100-115% of average requests, but event if I set it that high, I am starting to have 100% CPU load when, for example, node stops serving static pages.

Comment: @Amantel the pool size is 3000, or the number of concurrent queries?

Comment: The pool size is 3000. I am doing a lot of async quires, but I try to keep concurrent quires under 1000. I have ~100% CPU load (~590% for my 6 cores) and at mongostats **conn** value is slowly growing from 1-3 to 549, then stops. My point is, that mongo should not stain CPU that much in any case.

Comment: As a point of interest - I find it strange seeing so many mongo PIDs (https://pasteboard.co/GPCCbWB.png), when I should have one connection and a big pool.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157050/discussion-between-amantel-and-robertklep).

Comment: Chat discussion failed, so here is some additional info: with db.serverStatus - { "current" : 197, "available" : 51003, "totalCreated" : 1973 } I got 100% CPU load. Very strange. And with maximum of 3000 poolsize I see at mongostat 500 conn and again 100% CPU load